# Auto Populate a Drop Down List based on value in Text Box

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a simple password reset form that has a username field, and below it, a drop down list for security questions.

What I am trying to get working is when the user types in a valid username, when they unfocus from the textbox, I want to have it so that the drop down list will populate with the users security questions as found in my database.

Here is my HTML

```
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.userName, new { @Id = "forgotPassUserName" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.userName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-field">
    @{
        List<SelectListItem> securityquestionvalues = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.securityQuestion, securityquestionvalues, new { @Id = "forgotPassSecurityQuestions" })
```

Here is my jQuery/JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#forgotPassUserName").change(function () {
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
        $.getJson("LoginRegisterController/ForgotPasswordDropDownList", { user: selectedValue }, function (result) {
            var selectList = $("#forgotPassSecurityQuestions");
            selectList.add(result, null);

        });
    });
});
```

Here is the method in the controller that gets called by the getJSON above:

```
        public ActionResult ForgotPasswordDropDownList(string userName)
    {
        var db = IoC.ResolveObjectContextelearningCommon();

        var rep = db.GetRepository<EmployeeReg>();

        List<EmployeeReg> user = rep.Find(o => o.Login == userName).ToList();

        List<SelectListItem> questionList = new List<SelectListItem>();

        if (user[0].secureQuestion1 != null)
        {
            questionList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = user[0].secureQuestion1, Value = user[0].secureQuestion1 });
        }

        if (user[0].secureQuestion2 != null)
        {
            questionList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = user[0].secureQuestion2, Value = user[0].secureQuestion2 });
        }

        return Json(questionList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Unfortunately. This is not working for me. I unfortunately get errors when I try to breakpoint at the getJSON method. The issue seems to be in there.

**EDIT**

I changed my getJSON method to .ajax like so

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#forgotPassUserName").change(function () {
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
        var url = '<%= Url.Action("ForgotPasswordDropDownList", "LoginRegisterController") %>';
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            data: { userName: selectedValue },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                alert("testing");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Still getting no alert popup....

Comment: Can you describe the problem you are having?  Thanks!

Comment: And what happens when you run this code?

Comment: Unfortunately nothing. The Drop down list remains blank. I get an error when debugging at the getJSON method and when I try to put an alert within the getJSON function to see if that code gets reached, nothing happens.

Comment: My method in the controller (ForgotPasswordDropDownList) DOES generate the right values for me. I think it's cause I'm passing list of SelectListItems via json back to the jquery that I'm having major issues...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line isn't right:

```
selectList.add(result, null);
```

You'll need a `for` loop instead to add them to the Select List, something like:

```
selectList.html(""); //empty the options first

for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
{
    selectList.append("<option value='" + result[i].Value  + "'>" 
        + result[i].Text  + "</option>");
}
```

Comment: Interesting. However, there's one problem. If I replace:
                var selectList = $("#forgotPassSecurityQuestions"); 
            selectList.add(result, null); 

with
    alert("testing");

then shouldn't I get a message pop up on the change and success of getJson. I don't get anything unfortunately

Comment: Hmm strange, have you debugged the action method code to make sure there's no errors being thrown in there?

Comment: action method code as in the 3rd code sample I posted? Yes I have, and it returns the correct values if I hard code a string value in. I think I'm having problems passing the string value to that method though using getJSON

Comment: But even then, if I hard code a value and take out the passing of the variable, I should still be able to get my alert window to pop up, but it does not :(

Comment: Then it must the success function not hitting, convert your `getJSON` method to a `.ajax` method, then you can provide the `error` function, that way we can determine why the AJAX request is failing. Here's the `.ajax` method link (FYI `getJSON` is shorthand for `.ajax`): http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I just edited my original question with my ajax call. Still not much luck :(

Comment: Try adding `error: function (result) { alert("error"); }` and see if you get the alert

Comment: Hmmm. When I did replace the success with error, I am getting a pop up! I replaced the alert message with the 'result' variable that's supposed to be passed back and I'm getting '[Object object]' returned

Comment: Hmm okay, change it to `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(textStatus); alert(errorThrown); }` that will give you additional information on the error.

Comment: Out of curiosity, change your action method to return empty JSON(`""`) and see if you get the success alert.

Comment: hmm, nothing is happening... any idea what that could mean?

Comment: Well, looking at your code it seems your are mixing Razor `@` syntax in your view and ASP.NET syntax in your jQuery `<%`, put an alert on the variable `url` after you assign it and tell me what's in there?

Comment: If you are using Razor, you should change your `url` declaration to be `var url = '@Url.Action("ForgotPasswordDropDownList", "LoginRegisterController")';`

Comment: Great! Doing that with a few tweaks, I have it now spitting out a success alert as opposed to error allerts. I'm trying to work with my result variable in the loop you described above to no luck however... Do you think the app has a problem with passing around a List<SelectItemList> object between the method and the jquery?

Comment: Sweet! Hmm there should be no problem really, have you tried inspecting what's in the result variable inside the success function? Looking at `success.length` and maybe `success[0].Text`?

Comment: Is it success[0].Text that I write or result[0].Text? Both return nothing unfortunately... In fact, if I type in alert(success[0].Text); or alert(result[0].Text); I don't even get the alert to pop up anymore.

Comment: It's `result` sorry my bad. What about `result.length`?

Comment: I switched it from passing back a List of <SelectListItem> objects and made it pass back a simple string and it works way better. I don't think working with objects worked well with this at all. I even tried get it to pass back a list of strings and I had some major problems....

Comment: Ah fair enough, I've used Dictionarys before, never `SelectListItem`. Is it working now?

Answer (score 0):

to fire a event on change event use blur event .

```
$("#forgotPassUserName").blur(
```

this will properly fire the change event